# How to remove the existing markers in the following Heatmap and add a new set?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

The existing markers *(working)* have been assigned to the map using the N-blocks of similar set of longitudes and latitudes:

```
m = [42.0167, 24.8667];
marker = L.marker([m[0], m[1]]);
markers.addLayer(marker);
```

Where `m`, `marker` and `markers` are global variables.

Now, I would like to *clear* the existing markers on map and and place the new array of ajax data as soon as the `replaceWithNewMarkers(data)` is executed:

```
function replaceWithNewMarkers(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
    //markers.clearLayers(); // #this clears all the markers
    //markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    // THE FOLLOWING IS ABLE TO ADD NEW MARKERS TO EXISTING MAP
    $.each(obj, function(myVal) {
        m = [obj[myVal][0], obj[myVal][1]];
        marker = L.marker([m[0], m[1]]);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    });
}
```

This works fine for **adding** new markers, but I *cannot remove* the existing markers. I tried adding `markers.clearLayers();` to clear the markers but doing so hides the markers completely (without possibility of showing the new set of marks).

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

------- ADDED DETAILS -------

The following is initializer that is currently loading default markers.

```
<script>
    var m;
    var marker;
    var markers;
    var map;
    var tiles;
    var latlng;
    var baseLayer;

    window.onload = function() {
        tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
        });

        latlng = L.latLng(25, -80);

        map = new L.Map('map-canvas', {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 2,
            minZoom: 2,
            maxBounds: L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(85,-120), L.latLng(-85, 120)),
            layers: [tiles]
        });

        markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

            m = [40.27, 25.87];
            marker = L.marker([m[0], m[1]]);
            markers.addLayer(marker);

            m = [37.455, 20.94];
            marker = L.marker([m[0], m[1]]);
            markers.addLayer(marker);

            m = [57.25, 61.0];
            marker = L.marker([m[0], m[1]]);
            markers.addLayer(marker);

        map.addLayer(markers);

    };

        baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }
    );

</script>
```

Comment: What is `markers`? A LayerGroup?

Comment: Thank you @Krxldfx for the reply. I have added few more details, please have a look at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "map.removeLayer(markers)" to remove the layer

```
 function resetMarkers() {
    if (map.hasLayer(markers)) {
        map.removeLayer(markers);
        markers= new L.markerClusterGroup();
        map.addLayer(markers);
    }
 }


 function replaceWithNewMarkers(data) {
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
     resetMarkers();

     // THE FOLLOWING IS ABLE TO ADD NEW MARKERS TO EXISTING MAP
     $.each(obj, function(myVal) {
         m = [obj[myVal][0], obj[myVal][1]];
         marker = L.marker([m[0], m[1]]);
         markers.addLayer(marker);
     });
 }
```

// EDIT : renaming markerlayers to markers
// EDIT 2 : newMarkerClusterGroup => L.markerClusterGroup();

Comment: The console showed **ReferenceError: markersLayer is not defined** so I added *markersLayer* to the global var list. The error was suppressed but the old markers were not removed upon execution. In other words, the condition <code>if (map.hasLayer(markersLayer)) {</code> was not fulfilled. 

Suggestions?

Comment: MY BAD !!!  i copy this code from my project. 
Replace markersLayer  by markers in my code and remove the global declaration of markersLayer that you add.

Comment: Thanks @Alainlb, but it now tells **ReferenceError: newMarkerClusterGroup is not defined** All markers are cleared and script terminates there.

Comment: my bad two :)
newMarkerClusterGroup () is a function who recreate the layer. 
change it markers= new L.markerClusterGroup();

Comment: @Alainlb: Awesome! :)